# How to find Hospital Location near by my location?

Tags: android

I wanna idea about "`How to find Hospital Location near by my location`" using android,How is possible?,can i use google's database for get latitude and longitude value for Hospital location,How is possible?

Thanks All

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distance calculations are based on LatLong math such that:

Distance

This uses the ‘haversine’ formula to calculate great-circle distances between the two points – that is, the shortest distance over the earth’s surface – giving an ‘as-the-crow-flies’ distance between the points (ignoring any hills!).

Haversine formula:

```
R = earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
Δlat = lat2− lat1
Δlong = long2− long1
a = sin²(Δlat/2) + cos(lat1).cos(lat2).sin²(Δlong/2)
c = 2.atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R.c
```

(Note that angles need to be in radians to pass to trig functions).
JavaScript:

```
var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad(); 
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
```

Answer (score 9):

you can parse the xml : http://maps.google.com/maps?q=hospital&mrt=yp&sll=lat,lon&output=kml
where lat and lon are your latitude and longitude coordinates.

Comment: @Thank you very much!Vincent Porret,can you give some idea about kml handler and code for that url,then i want to hospital location for particular miles.

Comment: @vincent is there anyway to get JSON results?

Answer (score 9):

Step by step,

***Google place api are used to access near by landmark of anloaction***

**Step 1** : Go to API Console for obtaining the Place API

https://code.google.com/apis/console/

and select on services tab

[image: Service]

on the place service

[image]

now select API Access tab and get the API KEY

[image]

now you have a API key for getting place

---

**Now in programming**

***Step 2 ***  : first create a class named **Place.java**. This class is used to contain the property of place which are provided by Place api.

```
package com.android.code.GoogleMap.NearsetLandmark;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Place {
    private String id;
    private String icon;
    private String name;
    private String vicinity;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getVicinity() {
        return vicinity;
    }

    public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
        this.vicinity = vicinity;
    }

    static Place jsonToPontoReferencia(JSONObject pontoReferencia) {
        try {
            Place result = new Place();
            JSONObject geometry = (JSONObject) pontoReferencia.get("geometry");
            JSONObject location = (JSONObject) geometry.get("location");
            result.setLatitude((Double) location.get("lat"));
            result.setLongitude((Double) location.get("lng"));
            result.setIcon(pontoReferencia.getString("icon"));
            result.setName(pontoReferencia.getString("name"));
            result.setVicinity(pontoReferencia.getString("vicinity"));
            result.setId(pontoReferencia.getString("id"));
            return result;
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Place.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Place{" + "id=" + id + ", icon=" + icon + ", name=" + name + ", latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude=" + longitude + '}';
    }

}
```

Now create a class named **PlacesService**

```
package com.android.code.GoogleMap.NearsetLandmark;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;


public class PlacesService {

    private String API_KEY;

    public PlacesService(String apikey) {
        this.API_KEY = apikey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apikey) {
        this.API_KEY = apikey;
    }

    public List<Place> findPlaces(double latitude, double longitude,String placeSpacification) 
    {

        String urlString = makeUrl(latitude, longitude,placeSpacification);


        try {
            String json = getJSON(urlString);

            System.out.println(json);
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("results");


            ArrayList<Place> arrayList = new ArrayList<Place>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    Place place = Place.jsonToPontoReferencia((JSONObject) array.get(i));

                    Log.v("Places Services ", ""+place);


                    arrayList.add(place);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            return arrayList;
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlacesService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
//https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=28.632808,77.218276&radius=500&types=atm&sensor=false&key=apikey
    private String makeUrl(double latitude, double longitude,String place) {
         StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?");

        if (place.equals("")) {
                urlString.append("&location=");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
                urlString.append(",");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
                urlString.append("&radius=1000");
             //   urlString.append("&types="+place);
                urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        } else {
                urlString.append("&location=");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
                urlString.append(",");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
                urlString.append("&radius=1000");
                urlString.append("&types="+place);
                urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        }


        return urlString.toString();
    }

    protected String getJSON(String url) {
        return getUrlContents(url);
    }

    private String getUrlContents(String theUrl) 
    {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return content.toString();
    }
}
```

Now create a new Activity where you want to get the list of nearest places.

/**
 * 
 */

```
    package com.android.code.GoogleMap.NearsetLandmark;

        public class CheckInActivity extends ListActivity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);

        new GetPlaces(this, getListView()).execute();

    }


    class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private Context context;
        private String[] placeName;
        private String[] imageUrl;
        private ListView listView;

        public GetPlaces(Context context, ListView listView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context = context;
            this.listView = listView;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();

            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,placeName));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            dialog.isIndeterminate();
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PlacesService service = new PlacesService("paste your place api key");
              List<Place> findPlaces = service.findPlaces(28.632808,77.218276,"hospital");  // hospiral for hospital
                                                                                        // atm for ATM

                placeName = new String[findPlaces.size()];
                imageUrl = new String[findPlaces.size()];

              for (int i = 0; i < findPlaces.size(); i++) {

                  Place placeDetail = findPlaces.get(i);
                  placeDetail.getIcon();

                System.out.println(  placeDetail.getName());
                placeName[i] =placeDetail.getName();

                imageUrl[i] =placeDetail.getIcon();

            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```