# How to find Location near by my Current location?

Tags: android, location, google-places-api

I need some idea about "How to find Hospital,School,Restaurant near by my location" using android,How is possible?

Answer (score 21):

Step by step,

***Google place api are used to access near by landmark of anloaction***

**Step 1** : Go to API Console for obtaining the Place API

https://code.google.com/apis/console/

and select on services tab

[image: Service]

on the place service

[image]

now select API Access tab and get the API KEY

[image]

now you have a API key for getting place

---

**Now in programming**

***Step 2 ***  : first create a class named **Place.java**. This class is used to contain the property of place which are provided by Place api.

```
package com.android.code.GoogleMap.NearsetLandmark;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Place {
    private String id;
    private String icon;
    private String name;
    private String vicinity;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getVicinity() {
        return vicinity;
    }

    public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
        this.vicinity = vicinity;
    }

    static Place jsonToPontoReferencia(JSONObject pontoReferencia) {
        try {
            Place result = new Place();
            JSONObject geometry = (JSONObject) pontoReferencia.get("geometry");
            JSONObject location = (JSONObject) geometry.get("location");
            result.setLatitude((Double) location.get("lat"));
            result.setLongitude((Double) location.get("lng"));
            result.setIcon(pontoReferencia.getString("icon"));
            result.setName(pontoReferencia.getString("name"));
            result.setVicinity(pontoReferencia.getString("vicinity"));
            result.setId(pontoReferencia.getString("id"));
            return result;
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Place.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Place{" + "id=" + id + ", icon=" + icon + ", name=" + name + ", latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude=" + longitude + '}';
    }

}
```

Now create a class named **PlacesService**

```
package com.android.code.GoogleMap.NearsetLandmark;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;


public class PlacesService {

    private String API_KEY;

    public PlacesService(String apikey) {
        this.API_KEY = apikey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apikey) {
        this.API_KEY = apikey;
    }

    public List<Place> findPlaces(double latitude, double longitude,String placeSpacification) 
    {

        String urlString = makeUrl(latitude, longitude,placeSpacification);


        try {
            String json = getJSON(urlString);

            System.out.println(json);
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("results");


            ArrayList<Place> arrayList = new ArrayList<Place>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    Place place = Place.jsonToPontoReferencia((JSONObject) array.get(i));

                    Log.v("Places Services ", ""+place);


                    arrayList.add(place);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            return arrayList;
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlacesService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
//https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=28.632808,77.218276&radius=500&types=atm&sensor=false&key=<key>
    private String makeUrl(double latitude, double longitude,String place) {
         StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?");

        if (place.equals("")) {
                urlString.append("&location=");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
                urlString.append(",");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
                urlString.append("&radius=1000");
             //   urlString.append("&types="+place);
                urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        } else {
                urlString.append("&location=");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
                urlString.append(",");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
                urlString.append("&radius=1000");
                urlString.append("&types="+place);
                urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        }


        return urlString.toString();
    }

    protected String getJSON(String url) {
        return getUrlContents(url);
    }

    private String getUrlContents(String theUrl) 
    {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return content.toString();
    }
}
```

Now create a new Activity where you want to get the list of nearest places.

/**
 * 
 */

```
    package com.android.code.GoogleMap.NearsetLandmark;

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.List;


    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.ContextMenu;
    import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.android.code.R;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

    /**
     * @author dwivedi ji     * 
     *        */
    public class CheckInActivity extends ListActivity {

    private String[] placeName;
    private String[] imageUrl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        new GetPlaces(this,getListView()).execute();
    }

    class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        Context context;
        private ListView listView;
        private ProgressDialog bar;
        public GetPlaces(Context context, ListView listView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context = context;
            this.listView = listView;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            bar.dismiss();
              this.listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, placeName));

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
              bar =  new ProgressDialog(context);
            bar.setIndeterminate(true);
            bar.setTitle("Loading");
            bar.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            findNearLocation();
            return null;
        }

    }
    public void findNearLocation()   {

        PlacesService service = new PlacesService("past your key");

       /* 
        Hear you should call the method find nearst place near to central park new delhi then we pass the lat and lang of central park. hear you can be pass you current location lat and lang.The third argument is used to set the specific place if you pass the atm the it will return the list of nearest atm list. if you want to get the every thing then you should be pass "" only   
       */

/* hear you should be pass the you current location latitude and langitude, */
          List<Place> findPlaces = service.findPlaces(28.632808,77.218276,"");

            placeName = new String[findPlaces.size()];
            imageUrl = new String[findPlaces.size()];

          for (int i = 0; i < findPlaces.size(); i++) {

              Place placeDetail = findPlaces.get(i);
              placeDetail.getIcon();

            System.out.println(  placeDetail.getName());
            placeName[i] =placeDetail.getName();

            imageUrl[i] =placeDetail.getIcon();

        }





    }


}
```

Comment: @Ashish Dwivedi Thnks Dwivedi ji ... it worked for me like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google places api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) to find out near by hospital or what ever .....

Comment: Study the Google places api .There is an method to achieve this.

Comment: @shopnonill have a look my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291573/how-to-find-hospital-location-near-by-my-location/10479656#10479656) to use  place api