# How to use Google Places API in Android?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, google-places-api

I know the URL of accessing the google places. [check here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?&location=17.739290150000002,83.3071201&radius=6000&names=hospital&sensor=true&key=yourkeyhere)

But I am not able to parse the data coming from the URL in XML format. So, tell me the mechanism to display the data coming from google places API in xml format.

Please tell me some sample code or any tutorial for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want exactly? What are getting from XML parsing??

Comment: Hit the URL with a google api key will know what is returning.

Comment: It is returning `<PlaceSearchResponse>
<status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
</PlaceSearchResponse>` Please show your key here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344581/how-to-find-location-near-by-my-current-location/10479465#10479465 hear you can get the code for how to use place api in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse it by Json.

if you see your url contains `xml` [here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?&location=17.739290150000002,83.3071201&radius=6000&names=hospital&sensor=true&key=yourkeyhere) .   *This will give response in xml.*

output with xml:

```
<PlaceSearchResponse>
<status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

Just replace it with `json` like [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&location=17.739290150000002,83.3071201&radius=6000&names=hospital&sensor=true&key=yourkeyhere) .   *This will give response in Json.*

output with Json:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

see [this-blog](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/) for further help

For parsing

```
try
{
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&location=17.739290150000002,83.3071201&radius=6000&names=hospital&sensor=true&key=yourkeyhere");
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println(data);
    //parse with Json, Gson, Jackson

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: After that What next to do. I mean, I am getting data from Json. Now, how to show it in proper format. Actually, I am very new to Android.

Comment: @hotveryspicy, nice expiation i am going to implement in my app.

Comment: data is String(holds response).

Answer (score 1):

First go to this. [Link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&location=17.739290150000002,83.3071201&radius=6000&names=hospital&sensor=true&key=yourkeyhere) then other information about google places.

The Google Places API is a service that returns information about Places
  — defined within this API as establishments, geographic locations,
  or prominent points of interest — using HTTP requests. Place requests
  specify locations as latitude/longitude coordinates.

Four basic Place requests are available:

- [**Place Searches**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches)
      return a list of nearby Places based on a user's location.
- [**Place Details requests**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceDetails)
      return more detailed information about a specific Place.
- [**Place Check-ins**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceCheckins)
      allow you to report that a user has checked in to a Place. Check-ins
      are used to gauge a Place's popularity; frequent check-ins will boost
      a Place's ranking in your application's Place Search results.
- [**Place Reports**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceReports)
      allow you to add new Places to the Place service, and to delete
      Places that your application has added.

The Places API also offers support for events, which are defined as any type
  of public or private gathering, performance, or promotion that occurs at a
  location listed in the Places service. For more information, see
  [Events in the Places
    API](/maps/documentation/places/events).

([More](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/)). Here is best tutorial for  [how to use google places in android](http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html).

and go to this link also [Google’s Places API to Develop Compelling Location Based Mobile Applications](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/) another google map example([here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)). [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPO-6e8ijY8) for google developer for google places.

I think this might be helpful for you.