# How to get accuracy on location using GPS in android?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am toatlly new in getting the location using the GPS.

So for the reference I used this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/1395259

This is perfect for giving the location in latitude and longitude. But if I checked the accuracy using **location.getAccuracy()**.  It gives the output more than **500 meters**

I want the accuracy of the location below  **50 or 100 meters**.

Can anybody show me the way that how could I get the accuracy of the mentioned distance.

This help will be more useful to me and I will definitely appriciate it.

Thanks

Comment: if (location.getAccuracy() > 1000
                    && location.hasAccuracy())
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
http://devdiscoveries.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/android-use-location-services/ show for more

Comment: you can also use requestLocationUpdate method

Comment: @altaf The link provided seems better. Let me try to implement this.

Comment: @altaf I am not able to get it done. can you please elaborate more in answer thread??

Comment: Anybody please help me out guys

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Places API Application Form](http://gmaps-ws-console.appspot.com/) that you'll need to fill in in order to get access to the Google Places API. This application will be verified by Google and they'll provide you with the necessary access.

More info on the Places API can be found here :

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

There is a nicely explained answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291573/how-to-find-hospital-location-near-by-my-location/10479656#10479656).

Hope this helps :)