# How to find nearby hospitals with in a range of 5km radius?

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in which there is a page with the current app users location aligned to the middle of the
page and it will lists (hospitals, clinics and pharmacies) within 5kms radius from the current
location. The user can click one of the suggested places and it will show the details like name address and contact details in a pop-up window.
Please help me with sample code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find Hospital Location near by my location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291573/how-to-find-hospital-location-near-by-my-location)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of ways to do this.

One way to do this is to store all hospitals in a data structure. This data structure in this example could be a hash table system where you split the map into x number of sectors, and each sector contains the hospitals for that sector.

You can just check the sector you are currently located in, and the adjacent sectors that will give you *ROUGHLY* 5km radius.

The other simple way is to loop through all hospitals, and only display them if their distance is less than 5km from current location. But that's inefficient.